# Webrtc how to reconnect with the same peer after disconnect (I'm following the official webrtc doc please answer accordingly)

Tags: javascript, webrtc, video-streaming, audio-streaming, p2p

**First read the title, then please help me with the code example, write the code in the answer not just theory**

```
...

const configuration = {
  iceServers: [
    {
      urls: ["stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302", "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302"],
    },
  ],
  iceCandidatePoolSize: 20,
};


  const createPeer = async (user, ls, rs) => {
    ...
  };

  const joinPeer = async (roomId, ls, rs) => {
    .....
  };

 

  const registerPeerConnectionListeners = () => {
 
    peerConnection.addEventListener("connectionstatechange", () => {
      const state = peerConnection.connectionState;
      console.log(`Connection state change: ${peerConnection.connectionState}`);
      if (state === "disconnected" || state === "failed") {
        // remoteStream.getTracks().forEach((track) => track.stop());
        remoteStream = null;
      }else{
        remoteStream = new MediaStream() 
      }
    });

    peerConnection.addEventListener("iceconnectionstatechange ", () => {
      console.log(
        `ICE connection state change: ${peerConnection.iceConnectionState}`
      );
    });
  };

 ....
};

...
```

Please don't refer any third party library solution like peer.js or something... I'm following the official WebRTC [Doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/WebRTC)